# SQL 2 Table Query

Tags: sql

Fairly new to the SQL area of coding and looking for some assistance.

Essentially have 2 tables 1 for employees and 1 for instore which is where their payment details are stored.

Looking to have a query which lists their name and payment rate which are stored across the two tables.

So far I have

```
SELECT paymentRate
FROM inStore
WHERE employeeID IN (SELECT employeeID
                     FROM employee
                     WHERE employeeID = 'C1234567')
```

Which gives me the result of the payment rate. I need to have the name displayed with it which is stored in the employee table. However after a while of troubleshooting I am having difficulty with something I am sure is quite simple. However when I try to change my query I keep getting assorted errors. Any assistance would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have foreign key for `employee_id` in the inStore tablet, right?

Comment: Try something like: `select e.employee_name, inS.paymentRate from employee e, inStore inS where e.employee_id = inS.employee_id`

Comment: You'll get better answers if you provide your table schema, sample data, and an example of the results you are trying to generate.

Answer (score 0):

Hope your InStore table contains multiple records against a single employee. Please refer the below sql query. This query is written in T-SQL.

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE
(
    Id      INT,
    Name    VARCHAR(MAX)
)

DECLARE @InStore TABLE
(
    Id      INT,
    Rate    MONEY,
    EmpId   INT
)


INSERT INTO @Employee ( Id, Name )
VALUES  ( 1,'ABC'),( 2,'DEF'),( 3,'GHI')

INSERT INTO @InStore( Id, Rate, EmpId )
VALUES  ( 1, 10, 1 ), ( 2, 20, 2  ), ( 3, 30, 3 ),( 4, 40, 3 )


SELECT emp.Id,emp.Name,SUM(ins.Rate) 
FROM @Employee emp
INNER JOIN @InStore ins ON ins.EmpId = emp.Id
GROUP BY emp.Id, emp.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your query, you mean that you would like the employee name displayed when you do your query? If so you would want to use a Join as part of your sql query.

For example say that you want employee Bob Bobbins to show up you would need a query like the following:

```
SELECT i.paymentRate, e.FirstName, e.LastName FROM inStore as i

inner join employee as e on i.employeeID = e.employeeID
WHERE i.employeeID ='C1234567'
```

the as i and e are just ways to establish alias's so you wont need to keep retyping employee.firstname etc over and over again

hope that helps

edit: it would be good as well to have a foreign key relationship established as well for referential integrity purposes